# Qt cpp cant send obj to connected function

Tags: c++, json, qt, qnetworkreply

I need to get a json file from an url, fill it in a QtNetworkReply *reply and send reply in a connected fonction to convert it in QbyteArray to pars my Json response.

But when i go in my connected function, i cant fill QByteArray with that reply (always empty)
Here's my code :

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    Borne         borne(ac, av);
    reply          myReply;

    QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
    QUrl url("http://vps202498.ovh.net:8080/ws/rest/v.1/stores/categories/150/products");
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    myReply._reply = networkManager.get(request);
    QObject::connect(myReply._reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &myReply, SLOT(fonction()));
    myReply._reply->finished();
    exit(1);
    if (borne.initialize() == false)
        return (false);
    return (borne._app->exec());
}
```

And here's my connected function :

```
IProduct        *reply::fonction()
{
    QByteArray  List;

    std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    List = _reply->readAll();
    if (List.isNull())
        exit(6);
    return (NULL);
}
```

My .H :

```
class reply : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    reply() {};
    ~reply() {};

    QNetworkReply *_reply;

public slots:
    IProduct    *fonction();

private :

};
```

I cant std::cout "connected", but always quit with error log '6'.

I dont really know where am i doing mistake (Iam used to C, not Cpp), i've read all the man of Qt about it, and cant figure what going wrong.
Any ideas?

Thank you and apologize for weak skill and english

Comment: You need to process errors. Read about all `QNetworkReply` signals.

Answer (score 0):

You call the `finish()` function manually immediately after creation of the request. In that moment the request is not even started, so there is nothing to read from `_reply->readAll()`. The reply `finished` signal should be called by the even loop after calling application `exec()`.

Remove lines:

```
myReply._reply->finished();
exit(1);
```

The request will be processed asyncronously in the event loop.

---

Other issues:

- the slot `reply::fonction()` does not need any retrun value;
- the event loop may be not started because of `(borne.initialize() == false)`.

Comment: lil mistake,: 

I can print "connected", but always exit 6

Comment: Orest Hera : Thank you for your answer, well i've put an exit before the loop to be able to work on it easyly, but i thought the ->finished was a blocking signal. I know that i dont need to return, but later i'll need it for the program. I'll read qapp man.

Comment: @EtienneCtrs The returned data from the reply can be stored as a member of `myReply` to reuse it later.